# Как правильно оформлять цитаты в прямой речи?

Tags: пунктуация

Собственно, меня интересует, возможно ли в следующем примере убрать двоеточие или нет?

> Все говорят: «Выходите по одному с поднятыми руками, вы окружены», а ты купи слона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно § 143 [вот в этом источнике](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139) говорит о подобном случае цитирования:

> Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента,
>   выделяется кавычками (но начинается со строчной буквы), знаки
>   препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим авторским
>   предложением:
>
> *Мысль Л. Н. Толстого «время есть отношение движения своей жизни к
>   движению других существ», высказанная в его дневниках, имеет
>   философское содержание.*

Тогда в вашем случае пунктуация будет такая:

*Все говорят «выходите по одному с поднятыми руками, вы окружены», а ты купи слона.*